# Does a random variable's distribution also carry over to its histogram-estimated probabilities?

Tags: distributions, random-variable, continuous-data, discrete-data, histogram

If I

1. have a finite sample of a continuous random variable $x$ as a vector containing $N$ observations,
2. then I bucket those observations based on their frequency of appearance into equally-sized bins in order to model $x$'s histogram (a procedure known as **discretization** of a continuous random variable),

can I expect the distribution of the probabilities created in (2) to follow the same distribution as what belonged to the source data in (1)? For example, if the source data in (1) is distributed Normal, or t-, or Cauchy, or some empirical, then is it guaranteed that the discretized variable in (2) will also have a Normal, or t-, or Cauchy, or some empirical distribution corresponding to the original variable?

Comment: by "distribution of the probabilities created in (2)", do you mean the distribution of *normalized* histogram values (e.g. 0.1, 0.2, all sum upto 1)?

Comment: sure, probabilities have to sum to 1 so they're histogram estimates to me anyway given the binning makes them "normalized"

Comment: I'm having hard time to come up with such a distribution. It's as if you seek for a distribution that under the transformation with $f(x)$, the density should stay the same.

Answer (score 1):

The distribution of probabilities is not the same as the original distribution (or even its discretised version). For example, a standard normal distribution has values both negative and positive, but its histogram's probability values are only in $[0,1]$. Naturally, you wouldn't have the same histogram if you plot the *histogram* of histogram.

Comment: so you're argument is that the standard normal data has observations that are negative and positive causing the mean of that distribution to be $0$, which is the center of the range $[-\infty,\infty]$, whereas the "histogram of a histogram" would have a mean between $[0,1]$, i.e. $0.5$ ?

Comment: correct @develarist